# Kivy Buildozer vm ant build failing

Tags: android, python, ant, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to build the Hello World Kivy app on the Buildozer vm. Everything runs fine until Ant tries to compile the files.

I have attached the full error log and buildozer.spec

```
kivy@kivyvm:~/Documents/TestKivy/src$ buildozer android_new debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.10 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run 'python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build create --dist_name=howdyworld --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[INFO]:    Using Google NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.6', '4.8', 'clang3.3']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.8
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     howdyworld: includes recipes (hostpython2, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python2, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    howdyworld has compatible recipes, using this one
# Build the application #4
# Copy application source from /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src
# Create directory /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/app
# Copy /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/main.py
# Package the application
# Run "python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build apk --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name howdyworld --name 'Hello World' --version 0.1 --package test.app.howdyworld --android_api 19 --minsdk 9 --private /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/app --orientation landscape --copy-libs"
# Cwd /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi
[INFO]:    Getting Android API version from user argument
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[INFO]:    Using Google NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.6', '4.8', 'clang3.3']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.8
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     howdyworld: includes recipes (hostpython2, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python2, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    howdyworld has compatible recipes, using this one
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     howdyworld: includes recipes (hostpython2, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python2, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    howdyworld has compatible recipes, using this one
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/howdyworld
Listing /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/app ...
...
Compiling /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/howdyworld/private/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py ...
[INFO]:    Selecting java build tool:
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 23.0.1
[INFO]:        Building with ant, as the highest build-tools-version is only 23.0.1
[INFO]:    -> running ant debug
           working:     [javac] 3 warnings                                                                                                        Exception in thread background thread for pid 2274:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2170, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1929, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant debug

  STDOUT:
Buildfile: /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/howdyworld/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: HelloWorld-0.1
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 23.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for HelloWorld-0.1...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/howdyworld/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/howdyworld/bin/rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for HelloWorld-0.1...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found modified input file
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitkeep' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 26 source files to /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/howdyworld/bin/classes
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/howdyworld/tmp-src/org/kivy/android/PythonService.java:108: error: multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
    [javac]             } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException |
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
    [javac] 1 error
    [javac] 3 warnings

BUILD FAILED
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 7 seconds


  STDERR:


[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 75):

-pre-compile:   

-compile:   
    [javac] Compiling 26 source files to /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/howdyworld/bin/classes   
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release 
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release 
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.    
    [javac] /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/howdyworld/tmp-src/org/kivy/android/PythonService.java:108: error: multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5  
    [javac]             } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException |   
    [javac]                                            ^    
    [javac]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement) 
    [javac] 1 error 
    [javac] 3 warnings  

BUILD FAILED    
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:  
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.   

Total time: 7 seconds
[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/howdyworld && /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant debug

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant failed!
# Command failed: python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/platform/build apk --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name howdyworld --name 'Hello World' --version 0.1 --package test.app.howdyworld --android_api 19 --minsdk 9 --private /home/kivy/Documents/TestKivy/src/.buildozer/android/app --orientation landscape --copy-libs
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
kivy@kivyvm:~/Documents/TestKivy/src$
```

Buildozer.spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Hello World

# (str) Package name
package.name = howdyworld

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = test.app

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Any help with what may be causing this error or even how to see more of the Ant build error would be great.

Comment: "multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5"

Comment: Does that mean there's an issue with the python code? I see that error but can't figure out what is causing it from this simple code kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html  @CAustin

Answer (score 0):

I got same error but solved.

android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml
android-sdk-20/tools/ant/uibuild.xml

```
<property name="java.target" value="1.5" />
<property name="java.source" value="1.5" />
```

to

```
<property name="java.target" value="1.7" />
<property name="java.source" value="1.7" />
```

Comment: It's better to explain it a bit.